# Add product and coupon to cart together

Tags: quote, coupon, discount, addtocart

What I would like to do is add a product and a coupon to the cart at the same time from a product page.

The reasoning behind this is we are creating a landing page for a specific coupon and want to add both the product and coupon to the cart with only a single click for the user.

Comment: How to extend the functionality of this snippet to apply coupon when two products (different IDs) are in the cart? [Coupondunia](http://mycashclick.com/)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144506)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Have you tried event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` and  This event is sending  params `product cart params and product object` to Observer

```
 Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
);
```

That using this event you can add your coupon code

If you want `apply coupon from product page` then create `a input on product page or product add to cart url` and send `(coupon_code=yourcouponCode)`.

then you get coupon code at observer using `$oberver->getEvent()->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code')`

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote())->setCouponCode($couponCode)
->collectTotals()
->save();
```

Comment: you are welcome @DavidManners

Answer (score 0):

You could customize your add to cart button to use the querystring method

See [magento: URL querystring for adding product and applying discount coupon to cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232686/magento-url-querystring-for-adding-product-and-applying-discount-coupon-to-cart)

```
 http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add?Product=76&qty=1&return_url=http://www.example.com/index.php/checkout/cart/couponPost?coupon_code=WQ9D-XXXX
```

> return_url - need to be encoded

See /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

```
/**
 * Set back redirect url to response
 *
 * @return Mage_Checkout_CartController
 */
protected function _goBack()
{
    $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_url');
    if ($returnUrl) {

        if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($returnUrl)) {
            throw new Mage_Exception('External urls redirect to "' . $returnUrl . '" denied!');
        }

        $this->_getSession()->getMessages(true);
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
    } elseif (!Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/cart/redirect_to_cart')
        && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('in_cart')
        && $backUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl()
    )
```

Comment: this wont actually add the coupon code as this is done on a different action. I am thinking that I will need to hook onto an event on add to cart.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232686/magento-url-querystring-for-adding-product-and-applying-discount-coupon-to-cart

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to look at the SalguaMagentoAddProduct extension  https://github.com/salgua/SalguaMagentoAddProduct it provides the ability to do what you are looking for.